# how to check if all images loaded? (no jQuery please)

Tags: javascript, image

Due to the nature of async execution in .onload, Javscript would not run in the order as appeared in the code. Following snippet as I leared from  [how to alert after all images loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139709/how-to-alert-after-all-images-loaded/18723097#18723097) would not work always, pass here and fail there, all depending on the sequence of browser execution. Any suggestion how to solve it? (no jQuery please, nor asking me why)

```
var imgLoaded = 0;
var imgToLoad = 10;
var onImgLoad = function()
{
   imgLoaded++;
   if(imgLoaded == imgToLoad)
   {
      alert("done");             //Call to our draw function
   }
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  images[i] = new Image();
  images[i].onload = onImgLoad;
  images[i].src = 'images/'+i+'.png';
}
```

Specifically, here is where the code fails:

```
   imgLoaded++;
   if(imgLoaded == imgToLoad) { }
```

As a result, sometimes the code in the IF condition might not get executed even if all images were loaded corrected.

Comment: for each image, if image.complete !== true, return false

Comment: Based on the code you have here, imgLoaded will never equal imgToLoad.

Comment: In theory, imgLoaded should equal to imgToLoad at the end if the code runs in sequence. The problem is imgLoaded++ may be out of sync.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264528/image-preloader-javascript-that-supports-events/8265310#8265310 for an image preloader that will call a callback when all images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wdBbX/

```
var images = [];

function loadImages(callBack)
{
    var imgLoaded = 0;
    var imgToLoad = 10;

    var onImgLoad = function()
    {
          imgLoaded++;
          if(imgLoaded == imgToLoad)
          {
               callBack(imgLoaded);             //Call to our draw function
          }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
          images[i] = new Image();
          images[i].onload = onImgLoad;
          images[i].src = 'images/'+i+'.png';
    } 
}

loadImages(function(i){
    alert(i); 
});
```

Comment: imgLoaded++; if(imgLoaded == imgToLoad) { ... } would fail sometimes. The counter imgLoaded++ could be overridden by another onload call.

Comment: @yyc888 "counter imgLoaded++ could be overridden by another onload call." `imgLoaded++` will be incremented only. and it is what you want. isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

i prefer the sequentially way in this case.

so you can add cool animations with css...

```
var current=1,toload=10;
function next(){
 var img=document.createElement('img');
 img.onload=function(){
  current++;
  current==(toload+1)?(
   console.log('ALL IMAGES ARE LOADED');
   // callback
  ):(
   next()
  )
  document.body.appendChild(this);
 }
 img.src='img/'+current+'.jpg';
}
window.onload=next;
```

i also added the way to addan image array

```
var current=0,images=['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg','img4.jpg'];
function next(){
 var img=document.createElement('img');
 img.onload=function(){
  current++;
  current==images.length?(
   console.log('ALL IMAGES ARE LOADED');
   // callback
  ):(
   next()
  )
  document.body.appendChild(this);
 }
 img.src=images[current];
}
window.onload=next;
```

if your not shure about all images add also a `img.onerror` with the same function as onload esle the loop stops.

if you don't understand something or you need it as a callback function just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper up-to-date solution, including example usage:

```js
const preload = src => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = function() {
    resolve(img);
  }
  img.onerror = reject;
  img.src = src;
});
const preloadAll = sources =>
  Promise.all(
    sources.map(
      preload));

const sources = [
  'https://i.picsum.photos/id/1000/5626/3635.jpg',
  'https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667.jpg',
  'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png',
  'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png'
];

preloadAll(sources)
  .then(images => console.log('Preloaded all', images))
  .catch(err => console.error('Failed', err));
```

From [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/241578/223263).