# Canvas.drawImage simply just does not draw the image

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, canvas, drawimage

i'm trying to generate a tile-based-map, which works just fine so far, but after replacing all the "test-rectangles" with images to represent the ground, the path, some houses etc. (in this case its the same image for all of them), not a single image gets drawn down.

What am i doing wrong here? I also get zero errors.

Heres the code snipped:

```
    // generate a large map     
    Map.prototype.generate = function(){
        var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");        
        ctx.canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.canvas.height = this.height;        

        var rows = ~~(this.width/<?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize'] + $GAME['map']['tileBorder']; ?>) + 1;
        var columns = ~~(this.height/<?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize'] + $GAME['map']['tileBorder']; ?>) + 1;

        ctx.save(); 

        // Here i wanted to check if the image gets drawn right besides the player
        var testImage = document.createElement('img'); // Also tried new Image();
        testImage.onload = (function () {
            console.log(testImage + "-test");
            ctx.drawImage(testImage, 1000, 1000, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>);
        }());
        testImage.src = "http://192.168.0.140/img/terrain.png";

        var imgs = [];
        var imgIndex = 0;

        <?php echo "for (var y = 0, i = ".$tilesToLoad['xStart']."; i < ".($tilesToLoad['xStart'] + $GAME['map']['chunkSize'])."; y+=".($GAME['map']['tileSize'] + $GAME['map']['tileBorder']).", i++) {"; ?>

            <?php echo "for (var x = 0, j = ".$tilesToLoad['yStart']."; j < ".($tilesToLoad['yStart'] + $GAME['map']['chunkSize'])."; x+=".($GAME['map']['tileSize'] + $GAME['map']['tileBorder']).", j++) {"; ?>
                imgs[imgIndex] = document.createElement('img');                 
                imgs[imgIndex].onload = (function () {
                    console.log(imgs[imgIndex] + "-" + imgIndex + "-" + x + "-" + y);
                    ctx.drawImage(imgs[imgIndex], x, y, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>);
                }());
                imgs[imgIndex].src = "http://192.168.0.140/img/terrain.png";
                imgIndex += 1;
            }
        }

        ctx.restore();  

        // store the generate map as this image texture
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");                 

        // clear context
        ctx = null;
    }
```

console.log output:

```
 [object HTMLImageElement]-test
 [object HTMLImageElement]-0-0-0
 [object HTMLImageElement]-1-41-0
 [object HTMLImageElement]-2-82-0
 [object HTMLImageElement]-3-123-0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not having the desired effect because you have written the onload function as an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). It is executing the function immediately, before the src is assigned, and onload is not getting assigned to the function.

Change the first onload assignment to this:

```
    testImage.onload = function () {
        console.log(testImage + "-test");
        ctx.drawImage(testImage, 1000, 1000, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>);
    };
```

All I have done there is removed the outer brackets.
And the same for the later assignment:

```
    imgs[imgIndex].onload = function () {
            console.log(imgs[imgIndex] + "-" + imgIndex + "-" + x + "-" + y);
            ctx.drawImage(imgs[imgIndex], x, y, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>, <?php echo $GAME['map']['tileSize']; ?>);
    };
```

I suggest removing the `ctx = null;` assignment because if this executes before the onload events, then they will fail to draw the images on the canvas, instead you will get
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawImage' of null**

Also, as Blindman67 pointed out, a change is needed to get the image to be created from the canvas after all the onload events have fired.
To do this you could perhaps use a counter, similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139739/6854845) where an alert is shown after a set of images are loaded.

Comment: One thing you missed is the last two lines that convert canvas to an image with `toDataURL`. The `img.onload` events will not fire until after the `generate` function has exited. The OP will still not get the image he is after.

Comment: I changed it the way you have written it and now i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawImage' of null

Comment: Now i added `<img id="testpic" src="../img/terrain.png">` in my html file and tried to used the already loaded image by removing the onload function and changing the line that puts the image in the array to `imgs[imgIndex] = document.getElementById("testpic");` and even with this way there is no image that gets drawn... Just tried it in Firefox and it seems that this way does work in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: @Alex I have added a bit to the answer about the TypeError and the issue Blindman67 raised.